# Correct use of flatMap - would mergeMap or concatMap be more efficienient

Tags: angular, rxjs

as I have discussed in the past I am new to coding and trying to teach myself Angular - maybe it will lead to a new career! I am creating an app for myself to get to grips with Web Development. I am currently trying to use the Material Autocomplete in a form so that when a user adds/inserts a value to a text input the keyup event is listened too in an observable that makes an API call that returns some data and I use the returned date to populate an Autocomplete (I have 3 in my page). This is my HTML form...

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="assignmentForm">
      <div>
        <input type="text" matInput placeholder="User" formControlName="worker" name="worker" [matAutocomplete]="workerTemplate" #worker>
        <mat-autocomplete #workerTemplate="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let worker of workerTags" [value]="worker">{{ worker.displayName}}</mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Company" formControlName="company" name="company" [matAutocomplete]="companyTemplate" #company>
        <mat-autocomplete #companyTemplate="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let company of companyTags" [value]="company">{{company.displayName}}</mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Department" formControlName="department" name="department" [matAutocomplete]="departmentTemplate" #department>
        <mat-autocomplete #departmentTemplate="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let department of departmentTags" [value]="department">{{department.displayName}}</mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Now in my component I use Observable.merge to listen to all three inputs, I debounce so the user doesn't over load the system, I call my API and then do some formatting logic before populating the relevant data array for relevant Autocomplete. Here is my component code (I have reduced this for ease of reading)

```
public companyTags: any[];
public departmentTags: any[];
public workerTags: any[];

@ViewChild('company')
private companyEl: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('department')
private departmentEl: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('worker')
private workerEl: ElementRef;
private assignmentSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

public ngOnInit() {
  const companySource = fromEvent(this.companyEl.nativeElement, 'keyup');
  const departmentSource = fromEvent(this.departmentEl.nativeElement, 'keyup');
  const workerSource = fromEvent(this.workerEl.nativeElement, 'keyup');

  const tagsSource = merge(companySource, departmentSource, workerSource)
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      flatMap((ev: KeyboardEvent) => {
        // if the user presses backspace the value is "" and all results are returned (to set limit)
        if ((<HTMLInputElement>ev.target).value !== '') {
          return this.apiService.getTags((<HTMLInputElement>ev.target).name, (<HTMLInputElement>ev.target).value, 3)
        }

        return of([]);
      }),
    );

  this.assignmentSubscription = tagsSource.subscribe((res) => {
    this.clearAllTags();
    if (res.length > 0) {
      // the type is contained in the array so we can determine which array we need to populate
      // we can use interpolation rather than a horrible if then else
      this[`${res[0].type}Tags`] = res;
    }
  });
}

public clearAllTags(): void {
  this.companyTags = null;
  this.departmentTags = null;
  this.workerTags = null;
}
```

This all works will but I wonder if it is the most efficient way of doing this? I've done some reading on flatMap, mergeMaop and concatMap and I am unsure which is the best method to use for my case? Also should I put the logic contained in the flatMap somewhere else as it seems like it is the wrong place? I am unsure how I would even do this using chainging or adding another method to the pipe (.do?). Any advice and thoughts would be appreciated. If I am making no sense or am wording my question badly please state so and I will rewrite / edit. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you should use `switchMap` instead of either `concatMap` or `flatMap`, flatMap will keep the inner observable running and emit value even if there's a new value come in from the source input , in your case keyboard input. So what user end up see in the screen will be flashing his last input result + latest result.

for example when you try to search 'apple', you get 'app' through from your source input, then api will go search 'app', but just before api return you typed 'le' and now should return result for 'apple'. If flatMap is used in this case, it'll first display result for 'app' then quickly change to 'apple'. Whereas `switchMap` is used, 'app' api search request will be skipped( not really cancel but not emitting value) and return 'apple' search instead.